# What does the "no_round" font option in Sublime Text do?

Tags: macos, fonts, sublime-text-3

> // Valid options are "no_bold", "no_italic", "no_antialias", "gray_antialias",
>      // "subpixel_antialias", "no_round" (OS X only), "gdi" (Windows only) and
>      // "directwrite" (Windows only)

Was setting up Sublime Text 3 on my MacBook, and noticed this option. Toggling it seems to make the font slightly more spaced out, but I can't find any documentation anywhere on what "no_round" achieves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What does the “no_round” font option in Sublime Text do?

The previous behaviour of never rounding positions is available via the no_round font option.

> Text positioning on OS X has changed to match typical Core Text output (as used by TextEdit, Terminal, and Safari). For anti-aliased fonts, this means rounding glyph positions to pixel boundaries for small font sizes. **The previous behaviour of never rounding positions is available via the no_round font option.** Aliased font rendering has also been changed to use a different set of rounding rules, which should now match the terminal.

Source [Dev Build 2169](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4832)